# How do clear highlighted dates from jquery calendar at the time of click on button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have highlighted some dates in jquery calendar. Now I want to clear (unhighlight) that dates when I click on a button.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        // check if date is in your array of dates
        console.log(datesdata);
        var selecteddates = datesdata[date];
        if (selecteddates) {
            // if it is return the following.
            return [true, 'event', 'Tooltip text'];
        } else {
            // default
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});

$("#clear").click(function() {
    alert();
    $('#datepicker').removeClass('event');
});
```

Comment: Is the clear button placed on the datepicker itself? Or outside? Because maybe it's trying to remove a class that is not in the dom on that specific moment.

Comment: @CarlosMartins button is placed outside.

Comment: can you add a working snippet?

Comment: what is `datesdata` ?

Comment: the $('#datepicker').removeClass('event'); should be inside the .datepicker and you should pass the variables and conditions that you need to style the dates into the function from the click function.

Comment: @urbz datesdata is an array of date which comes from databse

Comment: @CarlosMartins can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove the class `event` from `#datepicker`. But the `datepicker` plugin doesn't apply that class to the `input`, instead it is added in the particular `td` 's of the DOM generated by `datepicker`.

What you need is to re-render the previously generated DOM (there may be other hacks, but this should be the standard way to do so). Code for that:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
```

Now, the trick would be to update the "inputs/options" for `datepicker` before invoking the above `refresh` option.

One way to do so can be to have a flag, say 'highlight', which when is `true` should add the class and vice versa for `false`.

```
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    // set flag to false on clear 
    highlight = false;
    // re-init the datepicker
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
  });
```

Here's a demo:

(I took some assumptions about `datesdata`, which you haven't provided and you are strongly advised to do so for any questions in SO)

```js
$(function() {

  // array of date objects, should highlight dates 5, 10 and 15 Dec
  var datesdata = [new Date("December 5, 2017 00:00:00"),
    new Date("December 10, 2017 00:00:00"),
    new Date("December 15, 2017 00:00:00"),
    new Date("December 20, 2017 00:00:00")
  ];

  // flag set to true by default
  var highlight = true;


  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      // convert date to time in milliseconds for comparison
      var datesdata_Time = datesdata.map(function(d) {
        return d.getTime();
      });

      if (highlight && datesdata_Time.indexOf(date.getTime()) > -1) {
        // if it is return the following.
        return [true, 'event', 'Tooltip text'];

      } else {
        // default
        return [true, '', ''];
      }
    }
  });

  $("#clear").click(function() {
    // set flag to false on clear 
    highlight = false;
    // re-init the datepicker
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
  });

  //additional
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    highlight = !highlight;
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
  });
});
```

```css
.event {
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid #f00 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />





<input id="datepicker" type="text" />
<input id="clear" type="button" value="clear" />
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="toggle" />
```